# Laravel 5.7 error return response()->json(['content'=>'a<br />b]); then it turns into <br \>

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am having the php error of returning the json api incorrectly, it is correctly affected by the html tag 
. Project 102tube.tv I am developing Laravel 5.7

I have data in api as follows:

```
$arr = ['contetn' => 'line 1 <br /> line 2'];
return response()->json($arr);
```

And the situation I'm having:

[image]

It is suffering from the problem of being replate from 
 to

Does anyone know why?

Comment: That is because blank row you entered. If you need a blank row try to insert `\n` instead of blank row.

Comment: This is weird, `/` should be escaped like this `\/`, not replaced by `\ `. I did tested your code and got `{"contetn":"line 1 <br \/> line 2"}` as intended.

Answer (score 1):

It's happning because once it will be encoded using json_encode the / will be stripped.

Laravel internally used `json_encode` to send response in json. If you would like to skip the slashes...you'll have to manually encode with option `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and send the response.

Like

```
$arr = ['contetn' => 'line 1 <br /> line 2'];

$res = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

return response($res, 200)
                  ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

For more details on json response check the documentation..
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses

Comment: @Jacksonit.org you are welcome! does ans relavent to your problem? Can you please mark this.